# The constraint matched an in instance declaration - MonoLocalBinds

Tags: haskell

The code is intended to take simple type classes that (at this point) model functional relationships between types.

```
> {-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

> class Foo a b | a -> b where
>     foo :: a -> b
>     
> class Bar a b | a -> b where
>     bar :: a -> b

> data A a = A a
> data B b = B b

> instance Foo (A a) a where
>   foo (A a) = a

> instance Bar (B b) b where
>   bar (B b) = b

> f :: (Bar bar b, Foo foo bar) => foo -> b
> f x = bar (foo x)

> --g :: String
> g = f (A (B "1"))
```

Imagine thats there's lots of these typeclasses, that you want to compose tother, but if you specify the types explicitly you don't want to specify every single one, you want a short hand or an alias for them

maybe compose these typeclasses into new typeclasses so that ammending one of the axiomatic classes, will automatically flow through to the derived ones.

```
> class (Foo foo bar,Bar bar a) => FooThenBar foo bar a where
```

and you can define

```
> f' :: (FooThenBar foo bar b) => foo -> b
> f' x = bar (foo x)
```

but you can't go

```
> f' x = bar (foo x)
> g' = f' (A (B "1"))
```

because the type of (A (B "1")), doesnt inhabit FooThenBar...

so you create an instance...

```
> instance (Bar bar b, Foo foo bar) => FooThenBar foo bar b
```

and GHC complains

```
• The constraint ‘FooThenBar foo bar b’
    matches an instance declaration
  instance (Bar bar b, Foo foo bar) => FooThenBar foo bar b
    -- Defined at catdog.lhs:37:12
  This makes type inference for inner bindings fragile;
    either use MonoLocalBinds, or simplify it using the instance
• In the type signature: f' :: (FooThenBar foo bar b) => foo -> b
```

ok...you put the MonoLocalBinds in...

```
> {-# LANGUAGE MonoLocalBinds #-}
```

and it works...but there is a bit of an alarm bell going off...I'm obviously logically saying...

FooThenBar a b c <=> (Foo a b, Bar b c)

is that a problem?...I potentially want to create a LOT of these, I feel as if I'm sort of abusing the system, and Ghc is hinting this may cause problems later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just asking for constraint synonyms?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

type FooThenBar foo bar b = (Foo foo bar, Bar bar b)

f' :: (FooThenBar foo bar b) => foo -> b
f' x = bar (foo x)

g' = f' (A (B "1"))  -- "1"
```